# WSO2 cloud identity server as IDP and Salesforce as service provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to setup WSO2 cloud identity server (stratoslive) as the identity provider and salesforce as a service provider. Basically in salesforce I want to leverage the salesforce federated single sign on feature and connect with stratoslive identity server. Will be helpful if anyone can give me a link to follow or can guide me with the steps.

I am relatively new to the identity and access domain and for one of my project I need to setup WSO2 startoslive as identity provider and salesforce as service provider and have to fit in SAML  in this process.

Thanks
Indranil

Answer (score 0):

These links should be helpful to implement your use case:

WSO2 SAML Single Sign-On with Google Apps Tutorial
http://wso2.com/library/articles/integrate-google-apps-wso2-cloud-identity/

WSO2 Identity Server Single Sign-On Documentation
http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Managing+Single+Sign-On

Salesforce SAML Single Sign-On Reference
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml.htm&language=en